# Updating a part of a page using AJAX in CakePHP

Tags: ajax, cakephp

I am using CakePHP2.3.6. I want to update a portion of a page, after some data are returned. I mean, I want to update that portion with the result data, using AJAX. Here, I don't want to use another page to populate the result and show that page in that portion. I'll give some code if you guys need, but I think no code is needed here, that's why I am not giving anything for now.

Please help me.

Thanks.

Comment: Well, I think some code is needed here since we are not a "script supply community". Please be specific about what you have tried, what the errors are you are getting etc. Because with a simple Google search you can find plenty of simple examples. So, show us the effort you put in this, otherwise we (the SO community) won't put effort in answering the question either ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#your-form").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:'your-url',
        success: function(data){
            $("#where-you-want-display-result").html(data);
        }

    });
});
```